# Running XSLT to RDF framework fails because of Saxon

Tags: java, xml, xslt, rdf, saxon

I´m using [Krextor](https://github.com/EIS-Bonn/krextor/wiki) to convert XML to RDF. It runs fine from the command line. 
I try to run it from Java (Eclipse) using this code.

```
private static void XMLToRDF() throws KrextorException, ValidityException, ParsingException, IOException, XSLException{

        Element root = new Element("person");
        Attribute friend = new Attribute("friends", "http://van-houten.name/milhouse");
        root.addAttribute(friend);
        Element name = new Element("name");
        name.appendChild("Bart Simpson");
        root.appendChild(name);
        nu.xom.Document inputDocument = new nu.xom.Document(root);
        System.out.println(inputDocument.toXML());
        Element root1 = inputDocument.getRootElement();
        System.out.println(root1);
        Krextor k = new Krextor();
        nu.xom.Document outputDocument = k.extract("socialnetwork","turtle",inputDocument);
        System.out.println(outputDocument.toString());
    }
```

I have the following problem problem

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/saxon/CollectionURIResolver
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.saxon.CollectionURIResolver
```

I have included Saxon9he in the classpath, and I have also added manually as a library in the project but the error is the same.

Comment: My guess would be that Krextor has a dependency on a specific version of Saxon. But I can't find that information easily in their documentation. The class CollectionURIResolver was in package net.sf.saxon in Saxon 9.1, but by 9.3 it had moved to net.sf.saxon.lib.

Comment: I followed your recommendation and I included manually the Saxon9.jar and now I get this error:Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.SecurityException: class "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Comment: I think you should ask the developers of Krextor about this. Perhaps they already include a version of Saxon, in which case putting another version of Saxon on the classpath is very likely to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am the main developer of Krextor.  And, @Michael Kay, actually a colleague of Grangel, so I will resolve the concrete problem with him locally.

So indeed the last Saxon version with which I did serious testing was 9.1; after that I haven't used Krextor integrated into Java but mainly used Krextor from the command line.

@Grangel, could you please file an issue for Krextor, and then we can work on fixing it together.

Indeed, @Michael Kay, for a while I had been including more recent Saxon versions with Krextor and updated the command line wrapper to use them (such as to add different JARs to the classpath), but I have not necessarily updated the Java wrapper code.